# Dropbox iOS SDK doesn't receive unlinked notifications from web / desktop

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

In my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, I set up my Dropbox account like so:

```
DBAccountManager *accountManager = [[DBAccountManager alloc] initWithAppKey:TADropboxAppKey secret:TADropboxAppSecret];
[DBAccountManager setSharedManager:accountManager];
[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] addObserver:self block:^(DBAccount *account) {
/* 
   This block should be executed "whenever a new account is linked or an existing 
   account is unlinked. The observer will be called regardless of whether 
   the account was unlinked using `-[DBAccount unlink]` or by the user on 
   the Dropbox website."
*/
}];
```

I then link my app to the user's Dropbox account (using `[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:myViewController]`).

The [Dropbox Sync API documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios) states that "The observer will be called regardless of whether the account was unlinked using `-[DBAccount unlink]` or by the user on the Dropbox website."

However, in my usage, this block seems to be called when an account is *linked*, but never when an account is unlinked from the Dropbox website or the user's desktop Dropbox environment (by deleting the app's folder).

What am I missing?

Comment: Hm that would sound like a bug. Please report exact steps for reproducing at  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: Submitted steps using the link provided. Thanks @Greg!